# How can Apex ( controller of page ) get files via a plain HTML form

Tags: apex

With plain HTML form

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/apex/SomeApexPage">
    <input type="file" name="hello">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

In `SomeVfPage.page` with an controller `SomeApexController.cls`

How can I get the content of the file in `SomeApexController.cls` ?
Or is there any other ways to POST files to `SFDC` with a plain HTML form ?

(this problem cause from [jQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/))

Answer (score 2):

You can directly associate the file to an Attachment record in your class:

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="SomeApexController">
    <apex:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!upload}" value="Upload" />
            <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" immediate="true" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="File Name" for="fileName" />
                <apex:inputText value="{!attachment.name}" id="fileName" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="File" for="file" />
                <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" id="file" contentType="{!attachment.ContentType}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class SomeApexController
{
    public Attachment attachment {get; set;}

    public SomeApexController() {}

    public PageReference upload()
    {
        Account account = new Account();
        account.Name = 'Test Account';
        insert account;

        // Insert the file as an attachment related to some record (in this case a newly created account)
        attachment.ParentId = account.Id;
        insert attachment;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got problem with the plain HTML form ( Ajax request by the jQuery File Upload ).
(If Apex were PHP, there will be `$_FILES`)
You response did not help me, but thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Apex is not php. If you're looking for similar functionality then you need to build something custom by using the Salesforce rest/soap api

Comment: I did tried the REST api but it is not support `multipart/form-data`

Comment: liratanak, what did you end up doing to find the file content?

Comment: @tggane, (seem to late, anyway :D) I was trying to create a VF page that possible to handle file update without refresh the page. First time I use the js File API and I worked, but sadly [File API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673542(v=vs.85).aspx) support only IE >= 10. Then I see [jQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) support IE <= 9 but (again) sadly I cannot post the `multipart/form-data` to Apex Controller ( I mean to Salesforce ).

Comment: So, did anyone find a solution to this as I'm having the same issue :(